# Exported package doesn't visible in runtime

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, bundle

I have following problem.

I have an OSGI based application and I need to use library org.chromiunm.debug.ui. I add this library and all related libraries to the target platform.

The class that I want to use from this library in org.chromium.sdk.ui.launcher package. For this I add in my manifest file following row:

```
 Import-Package: org.chromium.debug.ui
```

During development in eclipse this class is visible correctly and I can use it. But in runtime at first access I got an error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/chromium/debug/ui/launcher/WipLaunchType

What is the possible problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages in Java are not nested ... `org/chromium/debug/ui/launcher/WipLaunchType` is `org.chromium.debug.ui.launcher.WipLaunchType` which is class `WipLaunchType` in package `org.chromium.debug.ui.launcher`

Importing `org.chromium.debug.ui` does not include sub-packages, since you're not importing `org.chromium.debug.ui.launcher` you get an error on class `WipLaunchType` ...

If you had used bnd(tools) you would not have had to specify this import as bnd would have calculated it from your class files ...